# Looking for percentage within a specific entry in column R

Tags: r, data-analysis

I'm trying to figure out percentage by race in my data frame. Each race has a different population, so I'm trying to scale the prescriptions by race to see if there exist discrepancies within psychiatric drug prescriptions. My data looks like this:

```
Prescription.      Race            Frequency

Ambien             Black           3 

Ritalin            Black           2

Lamotrigine        Black           1

Xanax              Black           7

Wellbutrin         Black           4

Ambien             White           5 

Ritalin            White           10

Lamotrigine        White           8

Xanax              White           3

Wellbutrin         White           5

Ambien             Latino          4 

Ritalin            Latino          5

Lamotrigine        Latino          10

Xanax              Latino           3

Wellbutrin         Latino           4
```

I'd like to add a column that indicates percentages in terms of racial population. For instance, if 20 black patients exist, and 2 of them are prescribed Ritalin, that gives Ritalin a 10% prescription rate within specifically black patients. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tidyverse solution:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Race, values_from = Frequency) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric, function(x) scales::percent(x/sum(x)))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#>   Prescription. Black White Latino
#>   <chr>         <chr> <chr> <chr> 
#> 1 Ambien        17.6% 16.1% 15.4% 
#> 2 Ritalin       11.8% 32.3% 19.2% 
#> 3 Lamotrigine   5.9%  25.8% 38.5% 
#> 4 Xanax         41.2% 9.7%  11.5% 
#> 5 Wellbutrin    23.5% 16.1% 15.4%
```

Or if you want to keep the data in long format:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Prescription.) %>% 
  mutate(Percent = scales::percent(Frequency/sum(Frequency)))
#> # A tibble: 15 x 4
#> # Groups:   Prescription. [5]
#>    Prescription. Race   Frequency Percent
#>    <chr>         <chr>      <dbl> <chr>  
#>  1 Ambien        Black          3 25.0%  
#>  2 Ritalin       Black          2 12%    
#>  3 Lamotrigine   Black          1 5%     
#>  4 Xanax         Black          7 54%    
#>  5 Wellbutrin    Black          4 30.8%  
#>  6 Ambien        White          5 41.7%  
#>  7 Ritalin       White         10 59%    
#>  8 Lamotrigine   White          8 42%    
#>  9 Xanax         White          3 23%    
#> 10 Wellbutrin    White          5 38.5%  
#> 11 Ambien        Latino         4 33.3%  
#> 12 Ritalin       Latino         5 29%    
#> 13 Lamotrigine   Latino        10 53%    
#> 14 Xanax         Latino         3 23%    
#> 15 Wellbutrin    Latino         4 30.8%
```

---

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Prescription. = c("Ambien", "Ritalin", "Lamotrigine", 
                                       "Xanax", "Wellbutrin", "Ambien", "Ritalin", 
                                       "Lamotrigine", "Xanax", "Wellbutrin", 
                                       "Ambien", "Ritalin", "Lamotrigine", 
                                       "Xanax", "Wellbutrin"), 
                     Race          = c("Black", "Black", "Black", "Black", "Black", 
                                       "White", "White", "White", "White", "White", 
                                       "Latino", "Latino", "Latino", "Latino", "Latino"), 
                     Frequency     = c(3, 2, 1, 7, 4, 5, 10, 8, 3, 5, 4, 5, 10, 3, 4)), 
      class     = "data.frame", 
      row.names = c(NA, -15L))

df
#>    Prescription.   Race Frequency
#> 1         Ambien  Black         3
#> 2        Ritalin  Black         2
#> 3    Lamotrigine  Black         1
#> 4          Xanax  Black         7
#> 5     Wellbutrin  Black         4
#> 6         Ambien  White         5
#> 7        Ritalin  White        10
#> 8    Lamotrigine  White         8
#> 9          Xanax  White         3
#> 10    Wellbutrin  White         5
#> 11        Ambien Latino         4
#> 12       Ritalin Latino         5
#> 13   Lamotrigine Latino        10
#> 14         Xanax Latino         3
#> 15    Wellbutrin Latino         4
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>